# Sort on List<dynamic> gets dynamic instead of int in Comparator

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new to flutter and seem to be unable to sort List

[image: code 1]

code from picture:

```
_getConSites(BuildContext context) async {
    var conSitesRes = await Network().getData('/con-sites');
    var conSites = json.decode(conSitesRes.body);

    conSites.forEach((cs) {
      if (cs['gpsx'] != null || cs['gpsy'] != null) {
        double xDiff = pow((location.latitude - cs['gpsx']).abs(), 2);
        double yDiff = pow((location.longitude - cs['gpsy']).abs(), 2);
        double length = sqrt(xDiff + yDiff);
        cs['length'] = length;
      } else {
        cs['length'] = 0;
      }
    });
    conSites.sort((a, b) {
      return a['length'].compareTo(b['length']);
    });
    // print(conSites);
    setState(() {
      this.conSites = conSites;
    });
  }
```

with this code, i am getting this error:
`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '((dynamic, dynamic) => int)?' of 'compare'`

conSites is json decoded list of entries like this: `{id: 80, pseudo_id: 2019-04, name: xx Eurovea II, manager_id: 9, address: null, gpsx: 48.xxxx, gpsy: 17.xxxx, deleted_at: null, created_at: 2020-05-03T09:44:46.000000Z, updated_at: 2020-05-25T16:19:00.000000Z, length: 139.62085997829686}`

my goal is to order list according to the **length** value.

what bugs me is the fact, that when i use this code:

```
conSites.sort((a, b) {
      var t1 = a['length'];
      var t2 = b['length'];(t2));
      print(t1.compareTo(t2));
      return 1;
    });
```

it actually returns **1**s and **-1**s

```
I/flutter (11802): 1
I/flutter (11802): -1
I/flutter (11802): 1
I/chatty  (11802): uid=10133(com.example.koberaapp) 1.ui identical 1 line
I/flutter (11802): 1
I/flutter (11802): -1
I/flutter (11802): -1
I/flutter (11802): 1
I/flutter (11802): 1
I/flutter (11802): -1
I/flutter (11802): 1
```

so, how do i sort my list?

oh and also a side note - this worked:
`conSites[2]['length'].compareTo(conSites[3]['length']);`
, just not in the sort function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make it clear to dart that the return value of your sorting function will return an `int` type. This error can be resolved by casting the return value to an `int`.

```dart
conSites.sort((a, b) {
  return a['length'].compareTo(b['length']) as int;
});
```

Comment: wow, this simple i was trying the same with int.parse(*the return statement*) but didn't go through.
this one runs smoothly, thank you very much!